# How to install curses.h header file(or the package including it)in Linux?

Tags: c, curses

I want to use certain operations (like clearing the screen etc.) in C programs in Linux platform and I am informed that it can be done including **curses.h** header-file. But this doesn't seem to be available along with **gcc** package.

Please, tell me how can I install it?

Comment: The answers are going to be different, depending on the Linux distribution. You haven't said which one you're using.

Comment: @Daniel Kamil Kozar...ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 38):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

Comment: How can I get the manual for this header-file(in terminal)? @Linuxios

Comment: "man curses" is not working.It is showing "No manual entry for curses".

Comment: Can you tell me the function that clears the screen of terminal?

Comment: Still working for Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Answer (score 9):

On RHEL / Fedora / CentOS Linux, type the following yum command at a shell prompt as root user:

```
yum install ncurses-devel ncurses
```

Answer (score 6):

On Debian/Ubuntu/Deepin,use the following command:

`sudo apt install libncurses5-dev`

man document:

`sudo apt install ncurses-doc`

then:
`man ncurses`