# How to read single character input in a Linux terminal with C?

Tags: c, linux

I want a function that reads a single character at a time from input and returns it. It should read the character just as the key is pressed, not something like getchar where the user has to press enter for it to start working.

Comment: You have to change the terminal flags (using *termcap*) to not be line-buffering. There are plenty of tutorials and examples on how to do that all over the Internet. Then you need to poll the `STDIN_FILENO` descriptor to know when a characters is available to read (which can be done in multiple ways, also easily found).

Comment: hansoko, Curious, what do you want to happen when <Backspace> is pressed?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think you meant *termios*?

Comment: @IanAbbott One or the other, I always get them mixed up. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use curses.h it contains getch() which behaves the same way as getch() in conio.h which should answer your needs
[Check this article out on how to install it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277192/how-to-install-curses-h-header-fileor-the-package-including-itin-linux)
Hope it helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).